# Security exception in Huawei phone running Nougat

Tags: android

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: broadcast from android asks to run as user -2 but is calling from user 0; this requires android.permission.INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS_FULL or android.permission.INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS
   at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1665)
   at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1618)
   at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.getContentProvider(ActivityManagerNative.java:4195)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.acquireProvider(ActivityThread.java:5771)
   at android.app.ContextImpl$ApplicationContentResolver.acquireProvider(ContextImpl.java:2415)
   at android.content.ContentResolver.acquireProvider(ContentResolver.java:1507)
   at android.content.ContentResolver.call(ContentResolver.java:1477)
```

I don't know what happened. I just want to read data across processes via the following code:

```
context.getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().call(uri, method, arg, extras);
```

when this crash has happened, I am sure I do not involve any multi-user operations. This error occurs randomly when my apps cross the process via context provider. And I could not reproduce the problem on the Huawei model.

Answer (score 0):

use one of these permissions in your manifest

`android.permission.INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS_FULL`

or

`android.permission.INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS`

Comment: It not work. I tried. These two permissions are system permissions so even I add but it is invalid.

Comment: use this
    <permission android:name="android.permission.INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS_FULL" android:protectionLevel="signature"/>

Comment: You mean that this permission can be valid in the same signature? It is not necessary to have a system signature? I have seen this before, but I did not think deeply.

Comment: yes for that permission to run, Signature must be same

Comment: that's why it is throwing exception

Comment: This is very strange. Compared to the previous normal  version，I didn't do anything other than doing some registration broadcast listener and context provider call and this error suddenly became a lot, which made me difficult to understand.

Comment: focus on this one broadcast from android asks to run as user -2 but is calling from user 0

Comment: this means you are broadcasting from a user who maybe don't have the permission to run that broadcast

Comment: Unfortunately, adding this <permission android:name="android.permission.INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS_FULL" android:protectionLevel="signature"/> is also invalid. Compared to the previous normal version, no special broadcasts have been sent, and no changes have been made except for adding broadcast listeners. Suspicion is caused by other problems, but there is no conclusion yet.

Comment: From the Google Android source code, this error only occurs when the handleIncomingUser method check permission is sent in the broadcast ActivityManagerService.broadcastIntentLocked(). And the source callerPackage is android.I don't know if Huawei system is customized in this regard.